# Installed Ubuntu on a Intel I5 3330 (over a dh 77eb motherboard), networking fails

Tags: installation, networking, drivers

To my surprise network fails after Ubuntu installs.

1. `modprobe e1000`, did not get networking to kick off
2. `modprobe e1000e`, too did not load
3. Searched for the drivers on the intel [site](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh61cr.html), no linux drivers listed.

lspci reports

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1503] (rev 04)
```

Any idea on how to proceed ? Is there a place where I can map driver names (like e1000, e1000e) with the model numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map to the pci.id is in modinfo.

```
$ modinfo e1000e | grep 1503
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001503sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

To install the updated e1000e, you will need to download the file to your desktop, extract it and then, from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd Desktop/e1000e-2.3.2/src
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e
```

Each time a new kernel, also known as linux-image is installed, recompile:

```
cd Desktop/e1000e-2.3.2
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e
```

Obviously, to install all this, a temporary wireless connection is strongly suggested.

Comment: How to `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic` without a network connection ?

Comment: Beg or borrow a USB wireless from a friend or neighbor. If you cannot do that, you will need to download the parts and pieces individually on another computer and transfer them on a USB stick. Here is a post that describes the process, although the driver is different. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126 See post #6. A temporary wireless is strongly recommended.

Comment: While I posted the comment I knew I was silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the intel motherboard specifications I got a hint.

> Gigabit (10/100/1000 Mb/s) LAN subsystem using the Intel® 82579V Gigabit Ethernet Controller

I looked googled drivers for **82579V network ubuntu drivers**, and to my surprise I found it on the intel site. Crazy eh!! They dont list the drivers on the same page as the specifications. Got it [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet%20Components&ProductLine=Ethernet%20Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082579%20Gigabit%20Ethernet%20Controller).

The README too is not complete. You need to run `make install` in the **src** folder. That installs and updates the e1000e networking driver. Just `modprobe e1000e` and magic turns around.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers for the Intel e1000, e100e LAN controller are available for download from Intel.

Its the Gigabit (10/100/1000 Mb/s) LAN subsystem using the [Intel 82579V Gigabit Ethernet Controller](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet%20Components&ProductLine=Ethernet%20Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082579%20Gigabit%20Ethernet%20Controller)

Or visit [Intel Ethernet Drivers and Utilities](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/)

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I guess its more appropriate to accept someone else's answer, rather than own. Here goes.

Comment: No you can accept you own, if you want I'll delete mine.  When at work I'm a slow type.

Comment: Dont, your has one more link.

Comment: No its 13:30 over here. By the way, go ahead and accept your answer, by checking the little check mark.